Can I set up logging for Big query load job in a script that runs every-night on a Virtual Machine on google cloud platform
I have a bq load script that runs the following every night:
bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --encoding=ISO-8859-1 Big_query_destination_dataset.table  gs://cloud_storage_bucket_file.csv
The script loads  CSV file from a cloud storage bucket into a big query table- recently this script was failing nightly for 2 months but there was no logging set-up so I never got a notification that something was wrong, is it possible to set up logging in a similar manner to how to set up .py logs so that I can have a .log file which the script prints to after the query is ran either succesfully or unsuccessfully so I can quickly identify issues in the future?
Tried to the logging in the same format as a python script but no luck

Firstly, do not use VM, but batch services, like Batch or Cloud Run Job, it will be simpler and cheaper. Then, you can use and configure OPS agent https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent to get the logs
